# How can I use a Self Signed Certificate for authentication in IIS 7?

Tags: ssl, iis-7

I have an MVC 3 application running on IIS 7 that associates users to their client certificates during registration.

I am currently using an ECA certificate issued by ORC to login to this application locally.

I need to create self signed certificates that I can use to create new users in this application and assign to the self signed certificates.

I have created a self signed Certificate Authority Certificate. I used that certificate to sign a server and client certificate. The Certificate Authority is installed in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities of the Computer Account on the machine I'm using. The Client Certificate is installed in the Personal Store of my account.

With the above configuration, my browsers will only prompt me for the certificate issued by ORC, and not my self-signed certificate. How can I get the browser to prompt me for the self-signed certificate so that all communication with the server will use my self-signed certificate instead of the ORC issued ECA certificate?